# nodejs on azure returns 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I made a simple nodejs web app and upload to Azure,but it always returns 403 forbidden.

Request URL: https://wemwebconsole.azurewebsites.net/

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 403 Forbidden

How could I fix this issue? Is there anything wrong?

The files tree is as listed.

[image]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> <%= temp %></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var serveIndex = function(req, res, next) {
    next();
};
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

serveIndex = function(req, res, next) {


    function renderIndex() {

        var data = {
            hhh:'hahaha'
        };
        ejs.renderFile( path.resolve('dist/index.html'), data, 'utf8', function (err, str) {
            if (err === null) {
                res.status(200).end(str);
            }
            else {
                next(err);
            }
        });
    };
    renderIndex()
}

app.get('*', serveIndex);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 443);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
   "build": "",
   "dev": "",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "2.4.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4"
  },
}
```

Update:
Adding web.config does not work:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
        <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: is `process.env.PORT === 443`?, or if your server is behind a load balancer, is it forwarding 443 => `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835172/azure-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)

Comment: Change to  "app.listen(process.env.PORT || 443) " ,still doesn't work.

Comment: It won't work, I thought you control the server, you're not forwarding the requests to your app. Check the other question.

Comment: still does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <configuration>

    <system.webServer>        

  <handlers>

    <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>

  </handlers>

  <rewrite>

    <rules>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">

             <match url="/*" />

             <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>

        </rule>

   </rules>

  </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
```

OK,the specific web.config is here.

Comment: You saved me mate! Just for the record, had this issue with standalone IIS, without Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access kudu console to investigate the issue. 403 error could mean many things; either you don't have access to this site, the site is stopped or the quota is exceeded. For more information, you may refer this doc: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-issues.

Also, you may try to enable diagnostic logs to check the exact error message and see if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it throws the error `temp is not defined` on my site.

It works fine if I change the data Object to the following:

```
var data = {
    temp: 'hahaha'
};
```

Furthermore, you can follow the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225069/why-is-azure-giving-me-random-500-errors/45227963#45227963) to enable logging of stdout and stderr to troubleshoot the Node.js app in Azure.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo error, this issue is resolved in the comment below.Thanks any way!